# mysql 'Unknown column' error

Tags: mysql

What is wrong with this:

```
SELECT *, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT w.tag_word ORDER BY w.tag_word ASC SEPARATOR ' ') AS tags, 
MATCH (title, description, tags) AGAINST ('london') AS score 

FROM article G 
      JOIN tag_index I ON G.article_id = I.tag_target_id 
      JOIN tag_word W ON I.tag_word_id = W.tag_word_id 

WHERE I.tag_type_id = 1 AND MATCH (title, description, tags) AGAINST ('london')
GROUP BY G.article_id
```

I get the error 'Unknown column 'tags' in 'field list''

**UPDATE:**

Thank you Parrots for pointing out that I need the HAVING clause. I still can not figure out how to implement it. I can only guess it can not be done in one query and needs to be a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

Since "tags" a value you're creating using `GROUP_CONCAT` you need to use the [having clause](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3469351/The-HAVING-and-GROUP-BY-SQL-clauses.htm). Whenever you want to apply a condition to stuff *after* the grouping, use `having`. It works the same as `where` just after the grouping.

`Where` in your code example is trying to be applied to filter the results from article that will eventually be grouped to build things like "tags".

Comment: I still can't seem to get it to cooperate... any ideas how I should implement it?